# Robert Sheckley short story about a chaotic world

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have a vague memory of a short story that I think was by Robert Sheckley about a chaotic world without the usual laws. So, for example, the protagonist would open his inside jacket pocket to reach for his wallet (?) and a bat would fly out, to be casually crushed by the man with a ruler (?) ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a Robert Sheckley story. It's [The Petrified World](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54246). I read it in his collection [Can You Feel Anything When I Do This?](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?6029). The line you remember is:

> Sampson sighed, found a little green bat fluttering inside his jacket and absentmindedly crushed it with a ruler.

Comment: Brilliant!!! Thanks so much - hugely appreciated.